# Selecting a value based on matching the substring in where condition

Tags: oracle

I have a table called country which has column as shown below

```
countryname  statename 

 USA         TEXAS
INDIA        DELHI,MAHARASHTRA
ENGLAND      KENT
```

I want to select a country name by passing the `statename` as a parameter in a Stored Function.
But for the case, India , the `statename` has multiple values separated by ','

How do you put where condition in select  so that i get `countryname` as INDIA , but the parameter passed is either 'DELHI' or 'MAHARASHTRA' not both

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Consider to normalize your data

Answer (score 2):

Why not use LIKE?

For example, you do:

```
DECLARE @stateName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MAHARASHTRA';

SELECT countryName
FROM table
WHERE (',' || stateName || ',') LIKE '%,' || @stateName || ',%'
```

Comment: @peterm: since I append commas to either end before matching, that should handle the lack of leading and trailing commas

Comment: Another (similar) approach is: `WHERE INSTR(','||table.stateName||',',','||:stateName||',')>0`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query and let us know the result

```
WITH country(countryname,statename ) AS (
SELECT 'USA','TEXAS' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'INDIA','DELHI,MAHARASHTRA' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'ENGLAND','KENT' FROM dual)
----------
--- End of data preparation
----------
SELECT countryname 
from (SELECT countryname, regexp_substr(statename, '[^,]+', 1, level) statename
        FROM country
       CONNECT BY regexp_substr(statename, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
         AND PRIOR statename = statename
         AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL)
where statename = 'MAHARASHTRA';
```

Output

```
| COUNTRYNAME |
|-------------|
|       INDIA |
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you have decided to use RDBMS, you should normalise the data.

Suggested design is to have

```
COUNTRY     STATE
INDIA       DELHI
INDIA       MAHARASHTRA
USA         TEXAS
```

When you data grows large, assuming you keep searching by providing name of the state, you would index STATE attribute, and suggested design would help you.